# Survivor function for generalized gamma from flexsurvreg output

Tags: r, survival, gamma-distribution, nonparametric

I am trying to plot/generate a survival curve in Excel using the output from flexsurvreg in R. The below is a snapshot from R with the corresponding estimates (y axis values) for the time (x axis values). What I am trying to workout here is to find the formula (survivor function) so that I can utilise the mu, sigma and Q, and input them in the formula with the x time to derive the survival probability (est). Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

I have the below formula but couldn't seem to work it out. What do I use in Excel for parameters λ,
ρ and θ? Also what is the symbol for the inverted L (1-"symbol"...)?

[image]

```
> model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(times_start, times_end, type="interval2")~1, dist="gengamma")
> summary(model)

      time       est        lcl       ucl
1   0.0001 0.9999997 0.99998925 1.0000000
2   0.7500 0.9816506 0.96418918 0.9925972
3   1.5000 0.9576283 0.93061633 0.9765006
4   2.2500 0.9313854 0.89891294 0.9557631
5   3.0000 0.9039436 0.86637892 0.9333460
6   3.7500 0.8758569 0.83489843 0.9100642
7   4.5000 0.8474810 0.80269418 0.8856525
8   5.2500 0.8190645 0.77121572 0.8598327
9   6.0000 0.7907896 0.74101506 0.8343906
10  6.7500 0.7627940 0.71139692 0.8095247
11  7.5000 0.7351836 0.68223216 0.7843386
12  8.2500 0.7080405 0.65343742 0.7598395
13  9.0000 0.6814288 0.62553813 0.7359009
14  9.7500 0.6553980 0.60000777 0.7118262
15 10.5000 0.6299860 0.57422552 0.6886199
16 11.2500 0.6052217 0.54929040 0.6656909
17 12.0000 0.5811259 0.52477386 0.6417684
18 12.7500 0.5577132 0.50180913 0.6211054
19 13.5000 0.5349928 0.47941930 0.5990178
20 14.2500 0.5129693 0.45675548 0.5781297
21 15.0000 0.4916437 0.43630646 0.5577959
22 15.7500 0.4710136 0.41563113 0.5377886
23 16.5000 0.4510741 0.39591998 0.5176391
24 17.2500 0.4318181 0.37644159 0.4991532
25 18.0000 0.4132363 0.35699921 0.4807261
26 18.7500 0.3953181 0.33868996 0.4633486
27 19.5000 0.3780515 0.32104761 0.4468018
28 20.2500 0.3614234 0.30433455 0.4316692
29 21.0000 0.3454198 0.28849472 0.4178568
30 21.7500 0.3300261 0.27192302 0.4025915
31 22.5000 0.3152270 0.25752829 0.3882569
32 23.2500 0.3010068 0.24289575 0.3736206
33 24.7500 0.2742396 0.21549688 0.3472114
34 26.2500 0.2495949 0.19126148 0.3228955
35 27.7500 0.2269427 0.16794411 0.3033747
36 29.2500 0.2061545 0.14704253 0.2850157
37 30.0000 0.1964200 0.13719251 0.2763688
38 34.5000 0.1462971 0.08773012 0.2298020
> model
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(times_start, times_end, type = "interval2") ~ 
    1, dist = "gengamma")

Estimates: 
       est    L95%   U95%   se   
mu     2.985  2.730  3.239  0.130
sigma  0.839  0.621  1.133  0.129
Q      0.970  0.296  1.643  0.344

N = 225,  Events: 0,  Censored: 225
Total time at risk: 2734.501
Log-likelihood = -493.6735, df = 3
AIC = 993.3469

>
```